# Are these lines of JavaScript code equivalent?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've found this string in JavaScript code.

```
var c = (a.b !== null) ? a.b : null;
```

This is a shorthand of an if-else statement, however the value null is assigned if it is null. Isn't that **ALWAYS** equivalent to

```
var c = a.b
```

including all cases - exceptions, null, undefined, etc?

In another words, are these lines (always) equivalent?

```
var c = (a.b !== null) ? a.b : null;
```

-vs-

```
var c = a.b
```

Comment: It looks to me like a botched attempt at enforcing `c` to be either truthy or else `null`. That would have worked if it was `var c = a.b || null` for example, but since it's using `!==` it checks if `a.b.` is _exactly_ null, not just falsy.

Comment: @musefan This is a question about the code refactoring. Are questions about the code refactoring not always useful @ SO?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Haradzieniec, I have a blog post regarding short-circuiting about JavaScript and I hope it can somehow help you on deriving/refactoring code using short-circuits. Please do visit my site @ http://js-guru.blogspot.com/2015/08/javascript-short-circuiting.html

Comment: What if I told you they weren't equal :-)

Comment: @Haradzieniec: Based on the conflicting answers, it seems the real answer is "it depends"... which of course is equivalent to "no it's not always the same". I would suggest you modify your question to show how `a` is defined in full. That way people can answer with more certainty. As it stands, I feel this question is too broad as it is asking for a list of scenarios where it would be ok to refactor the code, and when it wouldn't be ok

Comment: This looks like a botched attempt to prevent issues when `a` is null or undefined (in that case it would be `a != null` instead of `a.b !== null`).

Comment: *Maybe* if it was purescript... side effects and what not

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, they **AREN'T NECESSARILY EQUAL** always if b is a getter that updates a variable. It's bad practice to code this way though

```
var log = 0;
var a = {
    get b() {
        log++;
        return log;
    }
}

var c = (a.b !== null) ? a.b : null;
// outputs 2
console.log(c);
```

```
var log = 0;
var a = {
    get b() {
        log++;
        return log;
    }
}

var c = a.b;
// outputs 1
console.log(c);
```

Comment: We cannot see any getter methods on the OP sir with due respect.

Comment: @Allan Chua. Yeah, so it could be anything :-) Just thought I'd throw it in there. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, though nice answer and i'm gonna up-vote your answer for the effort dude :)

Comment: Very good, missed by everyone else case. Not commonly used, but nice, thanks!

Comment: So basically, the question does not provide enough information to be answered reliably. Would you agree? Other answers conflict with this one, can't all be right surely?

Comment: @musefan - if the question is are these lines **always** equivalent or not, the answer would be reliably no :-)

Comment: @potatopeelings: Indeed I do agree with that based on your answer, but I debate if this then means that the others answers wrong? If they are wrong they should be downvoted, but it's difficult because it isn't their fault that the OP hasn't provided enough information. So then next we consider, does that make the question bad? At the moment everyone seems to think all posts on this page are amazing, and the logic of it just doesn't add up

Comment: @musefan I don't see any reason to downvote the other answers. They're not wrong when they say that the two lines are equivalent. They are. potatopeelings' answer is just showing us that side effects can occur differently between the two lines.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok: The reason for the side effects is because they do different things

Comment: @musefan This is no different than having different implementations of a function. They're equivalent functions with different side effect behavior. In the same way that var c = (a + a - a)(b + b - b) is also equivalent and will produce a different side effect. It's important to understand the ramifications of implementation changes but the functions are still equivalent.

Comment: Nice catch. In practice, even if someone coded this atrocity, incrementing `log` twice in the one-liner would likely be unintended behaviour, unless someone subsequently came along and implemented a messy fix on the messy bug, such as (`var c = (a.b !== null) ? a.b : null; log--; // because I can't figure out why it incremented by 2`). Any way you slice it, this is bad code.

Comment: In ES2015 (ES6) there are more cases that differentiate them, proxies for example.

Comment: I don't envy whomever writes that getter method. What a piece of junk.

Comment: Of course, this answer only applies if you're working in a JavaScript version that supports this getter syntax. If the code was written to target ES4 (IE8), then we can go back to saying they're equivalent.

Answer (score 19):

These statements are ***logically* equivalent.**

That being said, and as mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939610/3745896), if `a.b` has side effects, the statements will not result in the same program state.

This could be readily obvious in the form of `var c` having a different value depending on which of these statements are executed, or more hidden, if `a.b` modifies something elsewhere in the program.

#### Refactoring

As refactoring has been discussed, I'll touch on it briefly. As the above has hopefully made obvious, directly refactoring would *not be safe* in all scenarios. However, I would still recommend a refactor of one kind or another.

The two possible situations as I see them are:

1. `a.b` has no side effects, direct refactoring is safe
2. `a.b` has hidden side effects. This represents very unclear, confusing,
   and just downright **bad code**. It should be refactored so that all
   changes happening during the statement are *clear and obvious* to a
   reader (hopefully intuitively so, as well as supported by comments).

Answer (score 1):

As @potatopeelings already pointed out, the two possible statements are not always equivalent, since one can write obscure code, which will have different results.

However, if I see a code, like

```
var c = (a.b !== null) ? a.b : null;
```

I will assume that the code's intention is

```
var c = a.b;
```

so I will change it to make the code prettier. If I will be negatively surprised, that is, the code does not pass the testing phases due to this change, then I will try to find the author of `a.b` with git blame.

So, my answer is, that the two statements are not equivalent, but should be equivalent in well-written code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually not even

```
var c = (a !== null) ? a : null;
```

is guaranteed to be equivalent to

```
var c = a;
```

when `a` is resolved by a getter or an ES6 proxy handler on the global object.

Hence for instance, this assign to `c` the value 0:

```js
Object.defineProperty(self, 'a', { get: function() { return c ^= 1; } });
var c = (a !== null) ? a : null;
console.log(c);
```

while this assigns to `c` the value 1:

```js
Object.defineProperty(self, 'a', { get: function() { return c ^= 1; } });
var c = a;
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right, `var c = a.b` is exactly the same as `var c = (a.b !== null) ? a.b : null;`

My guess is the `null` in the ternary operator was meant to be anything except `null`, a default value if you will.

Comment: So assuming the intention was to provide a default value, then surely it wouldn't be safe to refactor the code in the way the OP has suggested. Instead the solution should be to change `null` to a default value, right?

Comment: @musefan right, but that's only if my assumption of what it was originally for is right.

Answer (score -3):

The reason for that confusingly odd syntax is because a.b might be an empty string OR undefined, and apparently an empty string is valid input.

Also, note:  a.b might be a function.